# Extra wrong-color pixels on Zabbix graph

Tags: zabbix

I have several graphs in Zabbix (version 3.4) that show unsigned integer values over time.  When viewed in the dashboard (as a graph widget), there are extra pixels around the lines that I can't explain.

Here is one of those graphs, and I have added red arrows pointing to the pink-ish and light-green pixels that I don't want to see:

[image: Graph with arrows pointing to strange pixels]

Where are those coming from?  How can I get rid of them?  Is it some strange antialiasing artifact that arises from the very closely spaced measurements?

Comment: What do you see if you zoom all the way in, to 1 hour or less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Zabbix feature:

> For data that show a longer period three lines are drawn - a dark
>   green one shows the average, while a light pink and a light green line
>   shows the maximum and minimum values at that point in time. The space
>   between the highs and the lows is filled with yellow background.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/visualisation/graphs/simple